# Node.js REPL - Change variables' outside of repl context

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I am working on a Node.js app, and am currently debugging it, and I was wondering if it is possible to have a repl running that could change variables defined in the node application itself, not in the REPL's context, is this possible?

For example, i could enter `var app = express()` into the REPL, and it would also set the variable in the server itself.

If so, how would I go about implementing it and making it secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access the run-time of another javascript interpreter, so if you would like to interact with your running application, you have a few options:

#### Embed REPL into application directly

Look into the [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module for adding a REPL inside of your application (your app could start, then show a REPL), and then the [VM](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module for specifying the exact context you are operating on inside the REPL.

Securing it is another thing entirely.

#### Connect to your application via some API inside a REPL

Set up some interaction model with your application, such as a [socket](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) and write both client and server independently. [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is an example of how this interaction works, but it would need to be adjusted for remote javascript execution.